# ggplot2 v2.0 Error: is.logical(na.rm) is not TRUE

Tags: r, ggplot2

ggplot2 v2.0

Consider the below example, this could be a bug.

```
df = data.frame(x=runif(100),y=runif(100))

#1. WORKS
ggplot(df,aes(x,y)) + stat_density2d(geom='density2d',n=100) 

#2. DOESN'T WORK
ggplot(df,aes(x,y)) + geom_density2d(stat='density2d',n=100) 

#3. WORKS
ggplot(df,aes(x,y)) + geom_density2d(stat='density2d')

#4. WORKS
ggplot(df,aes(x,y)) + geom_density2d(stat='density2d',n=TRUE) #NB n SHOULD be an integer
```

The 2nd line above doesn't work, reporting: `Error: is.logical(na.rm) is not TRUE`, the value of `n` is being passed to the `na.rm` parameter somewhere, instead of being packaged with the elipsis and handed off to the stat method call, whereby `n` is an accepted argument.

Comment: Yes, there was a similar question posted few days ago with a problem geom_smooth() did not work, but when I used stat_smooth(), it worked. Some regression in ggplot version 2.0 there seems.

Comment: Has there been a ggplot v1.2? I thought it went from version 1.X.X to version 2.X.X

Comment: Sorry my error, I meant 2.0, ill fix the question

Comment: If the geom is modified, to have an explicitly defined 'n' parameter (the same as it is defined for the stat), the problem goes away. It is definitely to do with it being handled inside the ellipsis.

Comment: I would report this on github. Hadley probably will want to do something to address this, I'd imagine. It's not the ellipsis really, it's R's argument name matching rules. The `n` matches no argument exactly, but then it partially matches `na.rm` and so is attached to that before being dumped into the ellipsis.

Comment: `...` comes after partial name matching for arguments: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Argument-matching

Comment: That sucks imo, why would it partially match 'n' against 'na.rm', when an argument 'na.rm' is already explicitly defined with a default value....

Comment: Argument partial matching is a feature, and a useful one, when using R interactively. It means that functions with long or repetitive argument names can be called with less effort when typing commands interactively. A downside of that useful feature is that sometimes you need to be careful constructing functions with lots of arguments to avoid pitfalls like this (and when programming you should never rely on partial matching).

Comment: I've filed a bug report: https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/1485